# Accessing private data members using friend class

Tags: c++, friend

I learnt that declaring a class as a friend class enables it to use the contents or members of the class in which it is declared. I used the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class two; // forward class declaration
class one {
private:
    friend class two; // friend class declared
    int a; // to be accessed later
public:
    one() { a = 5; }
};

class two {
private:
    int b;

public:
    two() {
        b = a; // intended to access 'a' and assign to 'b'
        cout << " " << b << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    one one_obj;
    two two_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Error is: `'a' was not declared in this scope`

What I've noticed in most examples of friend class is that constructor 'two()' will use 'class one' as the argument and later use the data member 'a'. But I wouldn't always want to make a new object as an argument to constructor two(). For example, calling constructor one() has already been done and the value of 'a' has already been set. Making a new object would mean doing that again, which might not be favorable. So what it all leads to is that, can I access members of class using friend class but without having to declare an object once again?

Comment: You meant `friend class two;` there. Also, it's unclear what you're asking. Indeed friendship does not imply you have to take the other class as a constructor parameter. I hope that helps.

Comment: yeah I actually meant friend class two. it`s been fixed. I wanted to know how to assign the value of 'a' to 'b'.

Comment: You'd first need to have that value `a`. Your problem isn't with friendship. Your problem is that no instance of class `a` actually exists (or is in scope where you seem to want one)

Comment: thanks, I wished to know whether there was any way I could get values without using class instances. But as you stated that I need one. Changed my code to use an instance of class.

Answer (score 1):

Class `two` being a `friend` of class `one` **only overrides the access checking**.

It still means you must actually **refer to** a `static` member of the class, or a non-static member of a specific instance of the class **the normal way**.

You might profit from choosing a tutorial or book from [The definitive C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and reading up about it all.

Comment: High time to link to the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list :)

Comment: @sehe: Yes, it is. Integrated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = a; // intended to access 'a' and assign to 'b'
```

Just because it is `friend` you cannot directly access it's members. You need to create `one` object to access it's members.

```
one o;
b = o.a; //now it should work
```